# How to make raw query to a Sqlite DB in Xamarin XAML

Tags: sqlite, xaml, xamarin

I need make raw queries to an sqlite db in Xamarin for Android and iOS. I can't use object oriented queries (`conn.Insert<Object>`, `conn.CreateTable<Object>`, `conn.Table<Object>`, etc).

Which library is the best to make full raw queries?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
conn.Execute("Your query");
```

Make sure you read their documentation as SQLite doesn't support all SQL queries.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Comment: How can i do "select"?... following the documentation (https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) i can create, insert, update, etc. But i can not select. This is my code:
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(App.Databaselocation);
await conn.ExecuteAsync("select y from t").ContinueWith((t) =>
{ 
    var c = t.Exception;
});

Comment: var result = await conn.ExecuteAsync("select y from t");  I guess u want to use the selected items within your code (otherwise u just run that sql query and don't do anything with it.